# Extract parameter / value pairs from an Uri as a Map

Tags: dart

How do I get the parameter / value pairs of an URL / URI using Dart? Unfortunately currently there is no built-in functionality for this problem neither in the *Uri* library or the *Location* interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a [queryParameters](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/route_hierarchical/0.6.1+1/index.html#dart:core.Uri@id_queryParameters) member of Uri that returns a Map

```
Uri u = Uri.parse("http://app.org/main?foo=bar&baz=bat");
Map<String,String> qp = u.queryParameters;
print(qp);

// {foo: bar, baz: bat}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Uri.splitQueryString](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Uri.html#splitQueryString) to split the query into a map.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  Map<String, String> getUriParams(String uriSearch) {
    if (uriSearch != '') {
      final List<String> paramValuePairs = uriSearch.substring(1).split('&');

      var paramMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
      paramValuePairs.forEach((e) {
        if (e.contains('=')) {
          final paramValue = e.split('=');
          paramMapping[paramValue[0]] = paramValue[1];
        } else {
          paramMapping[e] = '';
        }
      });
      return paramMapping;
    }
  }

// Uri: http://localhost:8080/incubator/main.html?param=value&param1&param2=value2&param3
  final uriSearch = window.location.search;
  final paramMapping = getUriParams(uriSearch);
```

Comment: Is there a feature request bug?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 // url=http://127.0.0.1:3030/path/Sandbox.html?paramA=1&parmB=2#myhash
void main() {
   String querystring = window.location.search.replaceFirst("?", "");
   List<String> list = querystring.split("&").forEach((e) => e.split("="));
   print(list); // [[paramA, 1], [parmB, 2]]
}
```